# Disruptor pattern with pull even handler

Tags: buffer, disruptor-pattern

I'm going to improve performance of existing solution introducing disruptor pattern. Existing solution contains single producer and consumer with shared byte buffer. In this scenario producer push data to shared buffer and consumer pull data from the buffer but disruptor pattern doesn't support to the pull event handler. Disruptor events handlers are being triggered automatically by the disruptor framework. any suggestions?

Comment: (1) Tell us what language you're using, (2) post some code, and (3) Ask this on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: I'm using Java as a development language. It is not possible to post actual  code here. You can see some sample code from this(https://github.com/LMAX-Exchange/disruptor/wiki/Getting-Started) link.  In this sample LongEventHandler being triggered automatically by the disruptor framework. In my scenario, I need to pull this data from disruptor instead of being triggered automatically.